# H. Cartan's "Variétés analytiques complexes et cohomologie"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

Does anyone know where I might find an online version (for free or purchase, translated or in french) of this paper by Henri Cartan from 1953? I know it was published in *Colloque sur les fonctions de plusieurs variables tenu a Bruxelles* but I can't seem to find a conveniently available copy anywhere. Probably there does not exist one, but any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper is included on volume II of Springer's edition of Cartan's collected works

- Henri Cartan, [Oeuvres - Collected Works II](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783662469088) (1979)

As far as I can tell it hasn't been digitized so far.

Comment: My apologies for this delayed reply. It was indeed useful to know this - thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the Myshkin's answer. An electronic version of the paper can be found here: http://www.inp.nsk.su/~silagadz/Cartan.pdf